# Trie data for searches in time ranges

Tags: design, api-design, data-structures, trees

I am developing an API responsible for returning the distinct searches made on a service given a date prefix.

Example data:

```
2015-08-01 00:00:18 %22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DeYbdd2ChagY%22
2015-08-01 00:00:19 %22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dnb.com%2Flc%2Fcredit-education%2Fbest-in-class-risk-management-strategy.html%22
2015-08-01 00:00:19 %22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncspin.com%2Fa-60-million-rip-off%2F%22
2015-08-01 00:00:19 %22http%3A%2F%2Fasianjournal.com%2Fnews%2Fnevadas-lieutenant-governor-a-supporter-of-education-a-better-economy-and-filipinos%2F%22
2015-08-01 00:00:19 http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbsnews.com%2Fpictures%2Fnew-kurt-cobain-death-scene-photos%2F10%2F
2015-08-01 00:00:20 %22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.waff.com%2Fstory%2F28241900%2Fstate-rep-files-bill-to-require-cursive-by-3rd-grade%22
2015-08-01 00:00:20 http%3A%2F%2Fpetsforpatriots.org%2FAdopt%2Foutreachtopetsinneed.aspx
2015-08-01 00:00:21 %22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jdsupra.com%2Flegalnews%2Ffor-at-issue-waiver-the-best-defense-13853%2F%22
```

The user for searching the data by given prefixes. The API should answer all the distinct queries that were made in the requested time range.

- `GET /queries/count/<DATE_PREFIX>`: returns a JSON object specifying the number of distinct queries that have been done during a specific time range

For example:

- Distinct queries were done in 2015: `GET /queries/count/2015: {"count": 573697}`
- Distinct queries were done in Aug: `GET /queries/count/2015-08: {"count": 573697}`
- Distinct queries done on Aug 3rd: `GET /queries/count/2015-08-03: {"count": 198117}`
- Distinct queries done on Aug 1st between 00:04:00 and 00:04:59: GET `/queries/count/2015-08-01 00:04: {"count": 617}`

The expected traffic is `100K` searches and `10K` click events per day per customer application. Customers may request up to 3 months of the time range. The data is updated weekly.

As the system will have an extensive search cadence and few writes, it is essential to represent the data by an effective search structure.

Based on the requirements, where it describes that prefixes do the time range searches, I thought to represent the data in a Trie tree or a Prefix Hash Tree, where each node of the tree represents a prefix of a date and with it has stored all the results of that date. Is this a good choice for representing the data? What other choices can I consider?

=== **Update** ===

I forgot to mention one crucial point: The application cannot depend on any database or external software. This is an exercise to evaluate the choice of data structure.

Thank you.

Comment: are you asking how to design a database, or is there some reason a database cant be used to solve this problem?

Comment: `The API should answer all the distinct queries that were made in the requested time range.` Only the  `count`?  `The data is updated weekly.` How is data updated? What's your data source?

Comment: @Ewan, the application cannot depend on any database. The question is know how to choose the best data structure. (I have updated the post with this information).

Comment: @Laiv, yes, the API only answers the number of searches performed in a given time period. The data source is another system that feeds this dataset.

Comment: seems like an ordered array of datetime, count would be enough, add an index for where the days/ month start to optimise. ie make a database.

Comment: @alves but what's your data source? a file? a remote service? a database?

Comment: @Laiv In this case, the data source is a file.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC your example dataset could
with perfect fidelity
be represented for the query count API as:

```
2015-08-01 00:00:18,    1
2015-08-01 00:00:19,    4
2015-08-01 00:00:20,    2
2015-08-01 00:00:21,    1
```

and there's just a handful of interval lengths supported:

| seconds | format |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Y-M-D H:M:S |
| 60 | Y-M-D H:M |
| 3600 | Y-M-D H |
| 86400 | Y-M-D |

plus monthly and yearly, but I will stop there.

> represent the data in a Trie tree or a Prefix Hash Tree .... Is this a good choice

No.

There is absolutely no reason to require that all entries of your
dataset be RAM resident and be accessed via random instead of sequential scans.
All up and down the memory hierarchy, sequential is going to offer
higher throughput every single time.
Additionally, it is worth your while to rely on solid battle-tested code,
rather than develop / test / tune new data infrastructure.

Use an RDBMS such as Postgres.
Construct a reporting table which replicates your count data,
so that (based on above four rows) we have in essence four
datasets stored in single table.
Define a compound [PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key)
of `(format, start_time)`,
where format is literally one of those four strings above,
or perhaps an `int` enum.

Now it is easy to rapidly answer online API queries.
Notice that your example dataset contributes several rows:

- four rows, with counts between 1 and 4
- a count of 8 for 2015-08-01 00:00
- a count of 8 for 2015-08-01 00
- a count of 8 for 2015-08-01

By the time we have daily summary counts, we're in a good position
to let the RDBMS offer aggregate values for 7, 28, 30, 31, or 365
day intervals. It's straightforward to extend the approach if
certain queries turn out to be very popular and expensive.

Storing aggregate counts, say at the daily level, lets
us read just a small number of blocks from disk, and
consume just a small amount of cache memory.
If some of the intermediate levels of aggregation turn
out to not be popular query targets, feel free to elide them.

The order of the compound PK columns is fairly important.
You want sequential read I/O performance,
and therefore all counts of a given aggregation level (e.g. "daily")
should be physically contiguous on disk.
There are other ways to organize the data,
but they risk putting a bunch of random reads (seeks)
into the mix.

If postgres is a bit heavy for you,
notice that sqlite could readily be substituted.
You don't even have to commit to using this or that one,
if your python app accesses the DB via
[sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core)
bindings -- just switch connect strings.

---

The core idea here is to maintain

1. Source of Truth records and
2. derived reporting records

Raw query logs (1.) are stored in the order they arrive,
or perhaps in timestamp sorted order which is nearly the same.
Summary counts (2.) at convenient granularity are re-computed
from scratch every now and again, or perhaps incrementally
updated if a count really needs to be fresh.
We maintain them because they are a better fit, a better
data structure, for rapidly answering numerous incoming queries.

For queries with an endpoint of "now" that require up-to-the-moment
figures, consult (2.) and then add on (1.) -- it's a more expensive
query but it's accurate.

Sometimes servers reboot. So you're absolutely going to have
to persist these records somewhere, probably in a filesystem.
A single binary sqlite file would suffice.

Simple CSV text files could be pressed into service in a pinch.
A hierarchy of timestamp-named directories, matching the API format,
is one approach, though it may involve an ugly number of open(2)
sys calls. Another approach is to put all the daily counts in a
single large CSV, and remember the seek() offset of perhaps
each start-of-month record. If you can bound the number of decimal
digits for biggest count value, another approach is to pad
records so they're fixed size and then a computed seek() offset
falls out of a calendar computation. Or abandon easy-to-debug
text format in favor of a binary file format.
Or instead of inventing wheels let well-tested software,
such as sqlite, do all that lifting for you.

Comment: I mentioned the Trie tree because the problem is to take into account that the system cannot depend on the database. This information was not in the initial post (my mistake), but I have updated it. As for your answer, it is complete and interesting. When inserting new records, I have to update all the rows where the start_time is comprised of the time of the new URL.  
I need to find a way to keep the URLs and not just the count since I want to count the distinct URLs. With each new count, I need to know whether or not the respective URL has already been counted.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, the exercise focuses on choosing the best data structure for the requirements. What is the data structure in memory that can efficiently answer the queries made by the API?